# How to fix `TypeError: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable ` in Django

Tags: django

I'm using LoginRequiredMixin in Django. However I got error.
`TypeError: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable`

It happen in this line
`if Speaker.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, is_deleted=False).count() == 0:` of this code.

```
class SpeakerListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'speaker/list.html'
    context_object_name = 'speakers'
    model = Speaker

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # if user does not have speaker, redirect to create view
        if Speaker.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, is_deleted=False).count() == 0:
            messages.error(request, _('xxx'))
            return redirect('speech:speaker_add')
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you know, how to solve this problem. Please help me!

Comment: Is `Speaker.objects` some kind of custom model manager? I don't really see anything wrong there. `filter(...).count()` is even used as an example in the Django docs.

Comment: A full traceback would be nice too.

Comment: The `LoginRequiredMixin` performs it's logic in the `dispatch` method, because you override that method your code is run first before the mixin and not ensured the user is logged in. Move your logic to the `get` method or use the `UserPassesTestMixin` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check if user is authenticated

```
class SpeakerListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
template_name = 'speaker/list.html'
context_object_name = 'speakers'
model = Speaker

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # if user does not have speaker, redirect to create view
    if request.user.is_authenticated and Speaker.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id, is_deleted=False).count() == 0:
        messages.error(request, _('xxx'))
        return redirect('speech:speaker_add')
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I understood when I use request user in LoginRequiredMixin, I need to check user is authenticated or not.